# Adding "FlexBoxLayout" to a project breaks compilation

Tags: android, android-flexboxlayout

I am trying to use `FlexBoxLayout` in my app, but I am running into errors continuously. I have tried all kinds of settings and configs, but different errors keep popping up. What I have now:

build.gradle (app):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0"
}
```

And this gives me the error:

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>       is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:5-131:19 to override.

When I add that `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"'` to my Manifest, I get the following problem:

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

And that is where I kind of give up, I don't even know what logs to go look at.

**Update** when I only add `flexbox` to the dependencies, the app crashes with a `NoClassDefFoundError` on the `androidx.core.view.ViewCompat` class.

Comment: Could You share a project?

Comment: @deadfish Unfortunatley, no. This is a commercial product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few steps to achieve this:

1 In project structure update gradle version to the newest

[image]

2 In app's build.gradle set `compileSdkVersion 28` and in dependencies convert libs to `androidx` according to https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
}
```

3 Sync project & Rebuild

4 Go to Your Activity class. Everything will be with red underline and imports will be grayed out. Remove grayed out imports. And import the rest with new import path which will contains `androidx`. Bear in mind that all widgets in xml layouts have to be changed too. It will be easy to find because when You run Your app You will get error similar to this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mimok.flexbox2-1/base.apk",
```

At this case I have wrong path to `CoordinatorLayout` which should be changed to `<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`.

Comment: I had to replace all appcompat classes with androidx (apparently I did use them somewhere), but after that, the project built and the `FlexBoxLayout` works, also in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
change
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

to
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha3'
```

You can read about this [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/hello-world-androidx.html).
Also, I suggest you in Android Studio 3.2 and go to Refactor->Refactor to AndroidX

Update here if this works for you.

Comment: That simple fix didn't do anything for me yet, I will try the refactor later (after I have read what AndroidX actually is ... ;-)).

Comment: Hmmmmm. I thought that was because you are using the new Material library with the legacy Support Library. usually you have to migrate android.support to androidx in order to use com.google.android.material.

Comment: I am not even using the compat library, just thought I could throw in the `FlexBoxLayout`. But apparently that wants AndroidX, which seem to be alpha and not production ready yet.

Comment: yes - it should come out in 1.0.0 very soon. If this is a new project you can try not using the compat lib at all. that might help in avoiding the problem.